# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: jsp, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm developing an Application , it includes a Registration page and i'm using Oracle database.. I'm connecting back end and front end(html,js and jsp) using jdbc in jsp programs..

Here is my code:

```
String fname=request.getParameter("f1");
String uid=request.getParameter("f2");
String email=request.getParameter("f3");
Long phnno=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("f4"));
String pwd=request.getParameter("f5");
String face=request.getParameter("f7");
String finger=request.getParameter("f9");
out.println(uid);
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Sindhu","project");
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from Shield where uid=?",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
pst.setString(1,uid);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
boolean f=rs.next();
if(f)
{
// some html code
}
else
{
PreparedStatement pst1=con.prepareStatement("insert into shield values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pst1.setString(1,fname);
pst1.setString(2,uid);
pst1.setString(3,email);
pst1.setLong(4,phnno);
pst1.setString(5,pwd);
pst1.setString(6,face);
pst1.setString(7,finger);
pst1.executeUpdate();
pst1.close();
String TABL = "create table "+uid+" ( "
      + "   site VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY, u_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, pass VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, "
      + "   url VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL" + ")";
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate(TABL);
      stmt.close();
}
rs.close();
pst.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(" "+e);
}
```

I have to check whether User Id already exists in Db and then if not, have to insert the details . Along with that I have to create a table with the name same as user Id..

Here is the table creation syntax in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE Shield
(
f_name varchar2(40),
user_id    varchar2(40) PRIMARY KEY,
email   varchar2(40),
phone  Number(11),
pass_id    varchar2(40),
face    varchar2(40),
finger   varchar2(40)
);
```

I'm using TOMCAT and I'm getting an exception:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number`

I'm getting same exception even when i changed the phone field type to `varchar2`.

What ever values I try to insert in oracle workspace directly, they are getting inserted and if i try the same in jsp, they are not...

thanks in advance,
sindhu

Comment: You have a query for `select * from Shield where uid=?` but you don't have a `uid` column in the table creation you show, just `user_id`. So which is right, what is the type of that column really, and which line is the exception reported against?

Comment: Thank u... I got the solution.... I changed Uid to User_id... that is the mistake i made...